# Can be $ \mathbb{Z_{84}} \times \mathbb{Z_{8820}} \cong \mathbb{Z_{2940}} \times \mathbb{Z_{42}} \times \mathbb{Z_6}$?

Tags: abstract-algebra

The following is an example (page 164) from the Adkins' Algebra textbook :

[image]

I don't understand "the number of invariant factors of M is 2". Is it defined to be 2, or it is a mathematical conclusion? In other words, is it possible that $s_1=2 \times 3, \ s_2=2 \times 3 \times 7, \ s_3=2^2 \times 3\times 5\times 7^2$, i.e., $M \cong \mathbb{Z_{2940}} \times \mathbb{Z_{42}} \times \mathbb{Z_6}$? If so, why?

Comment: **since the powers of the primes 2,3,and 7 occur twice** It is a conclusion.  $Z_2 \times Z_2 \not \cong Z_4$ and $Z_3 \times Z_9 \not \cong Z_3\times Z_3 \times Z_3$ so, no, you can not do that.  You can't "split" the $2^2$ or the $3^2$.

Comment: @fleablood, but how can we split $2^2 \times 2^2$ (i.e. one $2^2$ in each $s_i$)?! Can be $ \mathbb{Z_{16}} \cong \mathbb{Z_{4}} \times \mathbb{Z_4}$?

Comment: Because we were given separate $2^2$.  We were given a $2^4$.  If we were then we *couldn't* split $Z_{16} \not \cong  Z_4\times Z_4$.  $Z_a \times Z_b \not \cong Z_{a\times b}$ UNLESS $\gcd (a,b) = 1$.  But if $\gcd(a,b)=d$ then $Z_a\times Z_b \cong Z_d\times Z_d\times Z_{a/d}\times Z_{b/d} \cong Z_d\times Z_a\times Z_{b/d} \cong Z_d\times _{a/d}\times Z_b\not \cong Z_{ab}$.  But we can do $Z_{ab}\cong Z_{d^2}\times Z_{a/d}\times Z_{b/d}$.  Important to realize $Z_a\times Z_b \not \cong Z_{ab}$ unless $\gcd(a,b) =1$.

Comment: we were *NOT* given $2^4$... I meant to say.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$\mathbb Z_{84} \cong \mathbb Z_4 \times \mathbb Z_3 \times \mathbb Z_7$ because $4*3*7 = 84$ and $4,3,7$ are pairwise relatively prime.

$\mathbb Z_{8820} \cong \mathbb Z_4 \times \mathbb Z_9 \times \mathbb Z_5 \times \mathbb Z_{49}$ because $4*9*5*49 = 8820$ and $4,9,5,49$ are pairwise relatively prime.

So $\mathbb Z_{84} \times \mathbb Z_{8820}$ can be decomposed elementary as $\mathbb Z_4 \times \mathbb Z_3 \times \mathbb Z_7 \times \mathbb Z_4 \times \mathbb Z_9 \times \mathbb Z_5 \times \mathbb Z_{49}$ which can be "recomposed" provided we only recombine groups with relatively prime modulos.

We can *not* recombine $\mathbb Z_4\times \mathbb Z_4 $ to $\mathbb Z_{16}$ because we were given two elementary groups of powers of $2$; we can not combine them.  Nor can we "split and recombine" $\mathbb Z_4 \times \mathbb Z_3 $ to $\mathbb Z_2 \times \mathbb Z_6$ because, although $2*6 = 3*4$,  $2$ and $6$ are not relatively prime.

We can recombine $\mathbb Z_4 \times \mathbb Z_3 \times \mathbb Z_7 \times \mathbb Z_4 \times \mathbb Z_9 \times \mathbb Z_5 \times \mathbb Z_{49}$ as $Z_{4*7^2*3}\times Z_{4*7*3^2*5} = Z_{588}\times Z_{1260}$ if we wanted to.  But this wouldn't be invarient.

Bottom line:  We must use $(2^2, 3,7)$ and $(2^2,3^2,5,7^2)$ in any combination provided we *don't* combine non-coprime pairs and we *don't* split prime powers.

Answer (score 0):

The $M$ in the question is the product of two cyclic groups of even order and so has $3$ elements of order $2$.

Your alternative group is the product of three cyclic groups of even order and so has $7$ elements of order $2$.

If you understand how to get the top invariant factor you get the next one the same way on the elementary divisors not yet used: and they all gt used up since no prime occurred in more than two elementary factors.

Answer (score 0):

No, you cannot represent M that way.  Corresponding to each elementary divisor is a cyclic subgroup of M of that order, so that M is the inner direct product of those subgroups.  The invariant factors correspond to *cyclic* subgroups of M built up from as many of these elementary subgroups as possible. **But you cannot split up an elementary subgroup.**  Since there are two elementary factors of $2^2$ (i.e 4), each cyclic subgroup of M corresponding to an invariant factor *must have an element of order 4*.  You have split up one of the 4's into two 2's, but the resulting direct-product terms $\mathbb{Z_{42}} \times \mathbb{Z_6}$ does NOT have an element of order 4.

I believe it is permissible to group the elementary factors in other ways for the purposes of generating alternate direct-product representations of M, but for the purposes of 'invariant factors' I believe the requirement is that the groupings maximize the products [e.g the first grouping has to have 9 instead of 3].